# how do I merge items from a dataframe into a query?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, merge, iteration

i have a dataframe like this:

| tablename | columnname |
| --- | --- |
| t1 | crd |
| t2 | deb |
| t3 | lon |
| ... | ... |

and want to combine these 2 column into a query like this, (in Python)

sel crd from t1
union
select deb from t2
union
select lon from t3 ;

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you expect?

```
make_query = lambda x: f"select {x['columnname']} from {x['tablename']}"
qs = ' union '.join(df.apply(make_query, axis=1))
print(qs)

# Output
'select crd from t1 union select deb from t2 union select lon from t3'
```